# I can display data from JSON file with AngularJS but not the way I would like to

Tags: angularjs, json, nedb

I'm using AngularJS 1.6.4 and NeDB.

When I try to get every users in the database, NeDB return me a json file with every users.
So I try to display them with AngularJS but when I try to display them with     `ng-repeat="user in users"` I can only display them by using `{{ user[0].name }}` but it's only display one user instead of every users, I would like it to work by using `{{ user.name }}`.

**EDIT** : **This is how my JSON file looks like**

`[ 
  { _id: 1,
    name: 'Antoine',
    createdAt: 2017-04-18T06:42:18.473Z,
    updatedAt: 2017-04-18T06:42:18.473Z 
  },
  { _id: 2,
   name: 'Louise',
   createdAt: 2017-04-18T06:42:18.478Z,
   updatedAt: 2017-04-18T06:42:18.478Z 
  } 
]`

**EDIT 2: Trying the solution of @PansulBhatt**
[Pansul Bhatt's solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImLbZ.png)

Comment: Post your JSON data.

Comment: Why does it matter how you get the data? The point is *to* get the data, and if user[0].name works, then use that.

Comment: Sounds like you're not looping the correct property

Comment: `[ { _id: 1,
    name: 'Antoine',
    createdAt: 2017-04-18T06:42:18.473Z,
    updatedAt: 2017-04-18T06:42:18.473Z },
  { _id: 2,
    name: 'Louise',
    createdAt: 2017-04-18T06:42:18.478Z,
    updatedAt: 2017-04-18T06:42:18.478Z } ]`

Comment: Yes @nmg49 I totally agree with you but If I got 800 users, I think there is a better way than write {{ user[i].name }} 800 times

Comment: I think you map the wrong thing inside users, can you post what users contains ?

Comment: Can you create a plnkr file or fidde ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, first I would like to thank you very much for the answers about my question !
But I also want to apologize because it was an error from my controller.
My code was :

```
$scope.getAllUsers = function() {
    $http.get("users").then(function(response) {
        $scope.users = response;
    });
}
```

And I resolve it with a simple modification :

```
$scope.getAllUsers = function() {
    $http.get("users").then(function(response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to iterate over the entire JSON so instead of considering it to be a list why don't you try to iterate it like a object ,something like :

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
  <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
</tr>
```

Now you will have all the keys and all the values associated to those keys defined to you. I can help more if you could send the JSON but I think this would help.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid as your dates should be strings. Run the following snippet (I also used a date format).

You can display it using `ng-repeat` as the following:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [{
    _id: 1,
    name: 'Antoine',
    createdAt: '2017-04-18T06:42:18.473Z',
    updatedAt: '2017-04-18T06:42:18.473Z'
  }, {
    _id: 2,
    name: 'Louise',
    createdAt: '2017-04-18T06:42:18.478Z',
    updatedAt: '2017-04-18T06:42:18.478Z'
  }];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="user in users">
    {{user.name}} {{user.createdAt | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
  </div>
</div>
```

## [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xxvpvacw/)

---

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.user=[ 
  { _id: 1,
    name: 'Antoine',
    createdAt: 2017-04-18T06:42:18.473Z,
    updatedAt: 2017-04-18T06:42:18.473Z 
  },
  { _id: 2,
   name: 'Louise',
   createdAt: 2017-04-18T06:42:18.478Z,
   updatedAt: 2017-04-18T06:42:18.478Z 
  }];
```

Comment: Looks like a possible answer, can you explain why the scope is the missing bit?